# Errors thrown from here are not handled....bug

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsdictionary, xcode7

Could someone please explain why I'm getting this error based on where other code is located?

[image]

Why does this compile fine:

```
func serializeJSONData(jsonData: NSData) -> NSDictionary {
    do {
        let searchResultsJSON: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
        return searchResultsJSON
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("json error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        let returnDictionary = [:]
        return returnDictionary
    }
}


func parseForms(formsArray: NSArray) -> NSArray {

    var retVal = [SearchFormObject]()
    for form in formsArray as! NSDictionary { }

    return retVal
}
```

When when I switch the methods around like this:

```
func parseForms(formsArray: NSArray) -> NSArray {

    var retVal = [SearchFormObject]()
    for form in formsArray as! NSDictionary { }

    return retVal
}

func serializeJSONData(jsonData: NSData) -> NSDictionary {
    do {
        let searchResultsJSON: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
        return searchResultsJSON
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("json error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        let returnDictionary = [:]
        return returnDictionary
    }
}
```

I get an error on

```
let searchResultsJSON: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

Is this an IDE thing or do I have an actual error in my code??